# Get-ADComputer only prints partial name

Tags: powershell

When I run the following command, long names will only be printed partially.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name
```

Results for longer names will look like

```
MYSIMPSRV...
MACHINE02...
```

How can I print the complete name instead of having "..."?

Comment: Using `-expandproperty` or formating to a list, or table and auto sizing if needed.

Comment: Actually, that's quite strange.  If you are only selecting the name it should show properly.  As an aside, if you only need the Name remove `-Property *`.  No need to bring back all the extra properties.  Name already comes with the default set.

Comment: Thanks.  It was the -Property * that was causing it.  Once removed, the full name is displayed.